# Error when converting pandas data frame columns from string with comma to float with dot

Tags: python, string, pandas, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a pands data frame (read in from a .csv file) from string to float. The columns 1 until 20 are recognized as "strings" by the system. However, they are float values in the format of "10,93847722". Therefore, I tried the following code:

```
 new_df = df[df.columns[1:20]].transform(lambda col: col.str.replace(',','.').astype(float))
```

The last line causes the Error: 
AttributeError: **'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'transform'**

Maybe important to know, I can only use pands version 0.16.2.

Thank you very much for your help!

@all: Short extract from one of the columns

```
23,13854599
23,24945831
23,16853714
23,0876255
23,05908775
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df[df.columns[1:20]].apply(lambda col: col.str.replace(',','.').astype(float))
```

EDIT: If some non numeric values is possible use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for replace these values to `NaN`s:

```
df[df.columns[1:20]].apply(lambda col: pd.to_numeric(col.str.replace(',','.'),errors='coerce'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, your code resulted in the following Error: ValueError: ('could not convert string to float: Comm Fail', u'occurred at index Col1_Temperature')

Comment: AttributeError: ("'module' object has no attribute 'to_numeric'", u'occurred at index Col1_Temperature').....Maybe panads 0.16.2 does not have the "to_numeric" method?

Comment: I used "to_numeric" :-/

Comment: @Bahlsen - Is possible upgrade? If not, how working [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html) ?

Comment: YES! :-) convert_objects is working with Pandas 0.16. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should load them directly as numbers:

```
pd.read_csv(..., decimal=',')
```

This will recognize `,` as decimal point for every column.